# Installing Lazy Script on Kali Linux Using Git Cloning

Tags: linux, git, kali-linux, clone, github

I'm tryna use git cloning to install Lazy Script on my computer. However, whenever I try to clone it, it does not complete, nor does it give me an error code. It just goes back.

```
root@kali:~# git clone https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript.git
Cloning into 'lscript'...
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Is there a `lscript` directory created? Are there files in it? `git clone --verbose --progress` may tell you things.

Comment: @xenoid same result

Comment: This doesn't answer my question about the `lscript` directory, and I assume that `--verbose --progress` produced some output?

Comment: @xenoid Nope. And the lscript directory isn't created

Answer (score 1):

Old topic, but the directory must be empty.
Or you need to specify a empty directory.

```
git clone https://github.com/arismelachroinos/lscript.git lscript
```